# Java - Why does ImageIO.read(filename) return null and the input image gets overwritten with 0 bytes?

Tags: java, image, io

I have several methods that manipulate a .jpg image: mirroring on x and y axis, tiling it, converting to ASCII text, and adjusting its brightness. All the methods work properly except the brightness one. When I run the brightness method, there is a NullPointerException in `readGrayscaleImage()` (see below - instructor written code). The `BufferedImage` is null, however it isn't when the method is called from any other of my methods (mirrors, tiling, ascii all read the file correctly). Not only is the `BufferedImage` null, the input image it is trying to read gets overwritten with 0 bytes and cannot be viewed in an image viewer, which would probably explain why the `BufferedImage` is null.

Here is a working method that calls `readGrayscaleImage()`:

```
public static void tileImage(int h, int v, String infile, String outfile) {
    int[][] result = readGrayscaleImage(infile);
    int[][] tileResult = new int[result.length * h][result[0].length * v];
    for (int hh = 0; hh < h; hh++) {
        for (int vv = 0; vv < v; vv++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
                    tileResult[i + hh * result.length][j + vv * result[i].length] = result[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    writeGrayscaleImage(outfile, tileResult);
}
```

Here is the brightness method that results in the problem:

```
public static void adjustBrightness(int amount, String infile, String outfile) {

    int[][] result = readGrayscaleImage(infile); // NullPointerException trace points here

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
            if (result[i][j] + amount > 255)
                result[i][j] = 255;
            else if (result[i][j] + amount < 0)
                result[i][j] = 0;
            else 
                result[i][j] += amount;
        }
    }
    writeGrayscaleImage(outfile, result);
}
```

Here is the instructor-written code that reads a greyscale .jpg file and returns an array of integers:

```
public static int[][] readGrayscaleImage(String filename) {
    int [][] result = null; //create the array
    try {
        File imageFile = new File(filename);    //create the file
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);

        int height = image.getHeight();  // NullPointerException POINTS HERE - image IS NULL
        int width  = image.getWidth();
        result = new int[height][width];        //read each pixel value
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
                result[y][x] = rgb & 0xff;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ioe) {
        System.err.println("Problems reading file named " + filename);
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    return result;  //once we're done filling it, return the new array
}
```

Here is the instructor written method to write a .jpg:

```
public static void writeGrayscaleImage(String filename, int[][] array) {
    int width = array[0].length;
    int height = array.length;

    try {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);    //create the image

        //set all its pixel values based on values in the input array
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                int rgb = array[y][x];
                rgb |= rgb << 8;
                rgb |= rgb << 16;
                image.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
            }
        }

        //write the image to a file
        File imageFile = new File(filename);
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", imageFile);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Problems writing file named " + filename);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Wanted to comment but am not able to.)

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(filename);
```

Should this be

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
```

?  I don't even see an override of read that takes a string.

Comment: Yes it should be, I've been altering the instructors code slightly and missed that bit when I changed it back.